# long running or blocking process cause my JFrame wait and halt other activity

Tags: java

Recursively list large number of files and directories in Java cause my JFrame wait and halt other activity

if java listing a large file like C:// and D:// root, in my computer it would take approximately around 15 minutes. while java do the listing, it will halt my jframe from doing other activity because the program have to wait for the task to finish.

i use this method for file listing

```
File[] files = directory.listFiles();
```

[image]

how to make our jframe able to proceed with other activity while files listing still running

**ANSWER DETAIL :**

http://www.javacreed.com/swing-worker-example/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swing is a single threaded framework, this means that any long running or blocking process will block the Event Dispatching Thread, which is responsible for processing the Event Queue, including processing repaint events.

Don't do this...

See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

You could use a background `Thread` of some kind, but Swing is also not thread safe, so if you intend to update the UI while you're processing you will need to ensure the updates are called within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.

To make this easier, you could use a `SwingWorker` for this, see [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html).

As an example: [How to search subfolders and repaint a jTable with new data in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26477744/how-to-search-subfolders-and-repaint-a-jtable-with-new-data-in-java/26478059#26478059)